How can I (or at least, my suitcase) avoid the stairs when entering Cambodia from Thailand via Poipet as a non-Khmer pedestrian?
From my understanding based on some readings, one has to climb a rather long set of stairs to reach the Cambodian immigration officers when entering Cambodia from Thailand via Poipet as a non-Khmer pedestrian. This can be inconvenient if one has a heavy suitcase. How can I (or at least  my suitcase) avoid the stairs when entering Cambodia from Thailand via Poipet as a non-Khmer pedestrian?

Usually at places like that there will be locals available who will carry your luggage for you (for a fee of course)

I think there is a good news for you in the "Understand" section of this wikivoyage page. Here it suggests that the town has one main street that runs approximately southeast from the roundabout at the immigration offices. So, you can safely avoid the stairs, otherwise you will always find a flock of porters who come to help with no to less charges.
